# How to get moonlight drm working on ubuntu?

Tags: mint, moonlight, drm

I have a site with moonlight videos like this:

http://tvnplayer.pl/

When i run it under Ubuntu it gives me an error about DRM and movies are not played.

The strange thing is that Linux Mint (which is based on Ubuntu afaik) allows me to play the movies on the site.

So.. How to make Ubuntu to play it? How Mint guys solved it?

Answer (score 1):

Moonlight doesn't (and never did) support DRM-protected movies.

I see two possible reasons for it to work on Linux Mint:

- Wine.
- Somehow the site doesn't use the Silverlight plugin, but Flash (or HTML5, or something else) instead.

(I don't know anything about Linux Mint, so this is just guesswork).

Note that [Moonlight is dead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15248143/183422), so don't wait for that to be fixed/implemented.